# How to trigger event after completion of ajax request if global option is set to false?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

From jQuery documentation:

> If [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Ajax/) or [$.ajaxSetup()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) is called with the **global** option set to
>   **false**, the [.ajaxComplete()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/) method will not fire.

and same applies for [.ajaxSuccess()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxsuccess/)

So, is there any alternative way to trigger event once ajax request has been completed.

**Note:** I cannot change the `global` option value to `true` as I am tracking ajax response of other site.

Comment: Are you trying to trigger the even globally? Or just in a one-off instance? For one-off, after a specific ajax call, the "success" handler will still work. As for globally, on any ajax event, no, as that is what the "global: false" is precisely set to disable.

Comment: @Daved no no.. I am not the one to invoke ajax request I am just tracking the completion request and then have to trigger my custom event

Comment: Can you clarify what do you exactly do? Is that request initiated by other (not your) script? If so, it looks like [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery).

Comment: @hindmost CSRF that's a BIG NO thing... well I am creating a extension to add button and corresponding event on a site (in a same way buffer or hootsuite etc extensions adds their social share button on twiiter fb etc. Well I am do able to this but content board is loaded using ajax request so for next changed board my script doesnt work and I need to manually refresh the page to fire the event